# select models that more than 24 hours have passed since their creation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I think that question title is Self-Descriptive.

In fact I want to select all rows that **more than 24** have passed since their `created_at` attribute in laravel with **Carbon** and [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses).

```
$question = Question::where('created_at',/* what do I here*/);
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Show your code or this question is getting flagged soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$question = Question::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())->get();
```

[Description](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fetch-data-from-db-within-last-24h-how-can-i-do-that)

Comment: I updated question. I want rows that **more than 24 hours** have passed since their creation

Answer (score 1):

```
$question = Question::where('created_at', date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("22-11-2016"."-1 day")));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
Question::where('created_at', '<', now()->subHours(24));
```